# Which natural languages are supported by Google Cloud Natural Language API?

Tags: syntax, nlp, multilingual, google-cloud-nl

I can't find this crucial information in the official docs or here.
Which natural languages are supported by the service? Which languages will be supported in the near future?
I'm interested in POS tagging with lemmatization and dependency parsing. I tried analysing Russian, Polish and even Italian sentences and got a 400s (“The language ru is not supported for syntax analysis” etc.).
If advertising a service as multilingual, it would be fair to admit which languages are supported before having to register and enter credit card details.

Comment: The languages supported are listed on the home page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your discovery is correct.  On this [page](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/) it states "The Cloud Natural Language API currently supports English, Spanish, and Japanese for sentiment analysis, entity analysis, and syntax analysis."

The "Google Cloud Natural Language API" web page states under multi-lingual support: "*Combine the API with our Google Cloud Speech API and extract insights from audio conversations*".  The languages supported by the "Google Cloud Speech API" service are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/languages).  Russian, Polish, and Italian are supported.

Apparently you can use the Speech API with eighty-nine languages but only use the Natural Language API on three languages!

Answer (score 0):

Here is list of languages supported by Google Cloud Natural Language APIs (from official docs):

https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/languages

Russian language did not supported as for now, but is mentioned among the docs - so i hope soon (tm) it will be available.